# Syntax for nesting xml string into xml element

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I need something like this:

```
<xmlData><elementA> (*) </elementA></xmlData>

(*) <xmlData2><elementB>HelloWorld</elementB></xmlData2>
```

How can I insert the (*) xml string to the placeholder in xmlData (well formed XML)?
(parsed with tinyXML in C++)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you be use namespaces with one or both of the sets of XML? Then the inner XML can remain XML rather than having to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just use TinyXML to *create* your XML-DOM :-)

If you just want to use plain old printing, replace the following characters:

- "<"  with "&lt;"
- "&" with "&amp;"

I also like to replace ">" with "&gt;" for consistency.